# Efficient way to find nearest node in euclidean distance with networkx

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx

I am trying to implement Rapidly-Exploring Random Tree (RRT) using networkx library in Python.

In my code, each node is defined as `G.add_node(node_idx, pos = (x,y))`. The 'pos' attribute contains the position information of each node. One of the critical steps in RRT algorithm is to first randomly sample a point within the configuration space, then select a node with the shortest Euclidean distance as a parent node and create a child node with some step size. (assuming no obstacle is in the way)

A naive approach is to loop through all the nodes with respect to the sample point and calculate all the Euclidean distances, then return a node with the smallest distance. Are there any other better ways to achieve this? Or any built-in libraries that can do it for me?

Comment: Perhaps a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) would help?

Comment: Consider using [`scipy.spatial.KDTree.query`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query).